# VS2012 Debug Doesn't Launch Browser

Tags: debugging, iis, browser, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have an MVC4 application I've been developing for a while and until now I've been attaching to IIS in order to debug and frankly that's just becoming a pain, not to mention it's not always reliable.

I've just switching the project over to use IIS Express with a localhost url like:

```
http://localhost:54275/
```

Now when I hit F5 or choose an alternative browser in the Debug toolbar VS starts up and IISExpress starts and shows the application listening but a broswer isn't started or maximised and loading the page.

I've tried running VS2012 as admin and normal account but this doesn't seem to have had any effect on it.

Google didn't seem to throw up anything useful on this either. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click On Project, Click Properties:

[image]

Click this if icon below is not in your taskbar:

[image]

In your taskbar, right click this icon:

[image]

Find the application in the list:

[image]

Click to open the browser:

[image]

Comment: Slaps forehead ... start page ... duh!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, to automatically open IE on F5 (start debug) follow this procedure.

1) right click on Project, click Properties:

[image: VS2015 Project Properties]

2) set 'Current Page' or 'Specific Page' as Start Action.

Comment: This is a four year old question and you've just added the same answer as the already accepted answer.

Comment: I had the same problem just few hours ago, since i lost my private vs project configuration. And I thought it could be useful for someone else. The accepted answer is suggesting to launch the browser from IIS Express menu!